# Retrieve certain bootstrap card information from a group of bootstrap cards with JavaScript but always retrieve information from first card

Tags: javascript, html

I have a group of bootstrap cards. When i click a button in a card always retrieve  information from thirst card. document.querySelectorAll('.fa-bookmark') works properly but document.querySelector(".card-title") inside click listener retrieve the first card information. I want information from which card i click.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    document.querySelectorAll(".fa-bookmark").forEach(bookmark => {
        bookmark.onclick = function(event) {
            alert(document.querySelector(".card-title").innerHTML);
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for article in news.articles %}
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{article.urlToImage}}" alt="{{article.source.name}}">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <i class="far fa-bookmark"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-bookmark" id="dl_bookmark"></i>
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{article.title}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{article.description|truncatechars:100}}</p>
                            <a href="{{article.url}}" class="btn btn-primary" target="blank" data-external_id="{{article.source.id}}">Read</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```